# NodeJS, Express, Nginx and Jade... whats the deal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, pug

So I'm currently investigating what technologies/libraries etc to adopt for a new, rather large scale project...

Given my teams knowledge of NodeJS, JavaScript, Express and Jade (now Pug) I/WE would ideally like to adopt these for the new project.

However, the current sticking point is the way in which HTML is being served under Express using route middleware.

We all know that Node/Express does a pretty bad job of serving up static files, which is where Nginx comes in. I can understand and even implement an Nginx config that handles the serving of img/js/css static files but what I'm trying to find out is this...

Can the serving of HTML (generated by Jade/Pug), using Express routes be handed over to Nginx in order to boost performance? Or is it the case that if you're using Express routing, you have to accept that serving of HTML files will be slow?

Got to be honest, I'm not quite sure how all this fits together so am hoping someone can shed a little light on this ;-)

Thanks in advance guys and gals

Comment: If your HTML is static then you dont need Node, just serve it from nginx. If your HTML is dynamic then you need a server-side language to generate it, i.e., Node. Node is no different form any other server side language in that respect.

Comment: nginx is a load balancer. Multiple instances of node will run on 1 or many servers on private ports (3000, 8000 or whatever), and nginx will be public facing and load balance between them.

Comment: Thanks, no... the content will be dynamic. Data gets passed in and rendered via routing. So, am I right in thinking then that we just have to accept the slowness of Node in serving up HTML? How does Node compare to say PHP at serving dynamic HTML pages? :-/

Comment: @AdamJeffers sorry but.. while the question speaks of static files, your comment speaks about dynamic ones. If they're dynamic, you can think about caching via Varnish ore some other logic; it they're fully static, you can avoid touching node.js and send it through Nginx; and yet, i don't find express' static file serving _that_ slow.

Comment: @sixFingers, no need to apologise, my question probably sounds confused because I am ;-) WIll look into Varnish

Comment: You can serve static HTML with nginx.  But, if the HTML is dynamically generated in Express using jade, then you can't serve it with nginx because the content is created in Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasonable recommendations:

- Serve static files with NGINX, you can configure it to fetch the
  files directly.
- Serve dynamic files with NGINX proxied to your express app, and set an adequate cache value.

> Can the serving of HTML (generated by Jade/Pug), using Express routes
>   be handed over to Nginx in order to boost performance?

Yes if you cache.

> Or is it the case that if you're using Express routing, you have to
>   accept that serving of HTML files will be slow?

Not if you cache.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Without questioning for more details, I can point out some things i keep in mind when developing on Express:

- Express "default" rendering done through `res.render` may not be optimal for a number of reasons. For example, lookup for the template file which is recalculated *every* request
- Jade template engine doesn't support streaming

I would suggest, before looking at interventions outside application context (such as Varnish or plain Nginx conf), to try:

- using a template engine supporting streaming: [Marko](https://github.com/marko-js/marko), [Dust](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs), [Nunjucks](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks)
- if the app is a single-page, or generally an ajax based one, and you don't need any special SEO setup (although, there are fixes for that too), you may also pre-cache the static html then fill it up on the client (but this is really just a rant).

A good overview comes from [Strongloop's blog post](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/bypassing-express-view-rendering-for-speed-and-modularity/)

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't support streaming"? Streaming of what? I've built a WebRTC app with Jade before and thats streaming video and audio.

Comment: HTTP streaming means that you can actually _start_ sending a response immediately, thus triggering refresh on the client, and _then_ send the rest incrementally. This is done internally in Node.js when using, for example, `req.pipe`. Another blog post explaining it better than me is [here](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/streaming-chunked-html-node-js-data/).

Comment: In production mode, templates are cached. Also, I doubt streaming will give noticable performance improvements.

Comment: In general, i find the problem pretty vague, so yes, i agree this may not be _the_ solution. But i must say Jade's performance is not the best in town, so i still feel @AdamJeffers may benefit from a better template engine. As for streaming, it's not really about performance, which is basically the same, it's more about _perception_ of speed.