# How can I serve dynamic files (pug/jade) with NGINX proxied to my express app by caching?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, pug, nginx-reverse-proxy

Heres my situation. I have switched all of my html files to pug/jade, and my app runs fine locally. However, after pushing my changes, all I get when I try accessing my website https://yesdevil.com/ is "cannot get /". I did some research and found that I must cache to be able to serve pug/jade files with nginx. I've had no luck in attempting to do this. Here is my github repository https://github.com/lojoba64/YesDevilWebsite

Here is my nginx configuration

nginx.conf

```
`http {
include etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/mycache keys_zone=:mycache:10m;
}`
```

etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yesdevil.com

```
`server {
    location /public {
        root /var/www/yesdevil.com/html/YesDevilWebsite/;
    }
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.yesdevil.com yesdevil.com;
    proxy_cache mycache;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://yesdevil.com:8080/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}`
```

Anything helps, thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you want to bypass cache to request dynamic pug files?  That's how we have our CDN set up.  If the pug files really are static (and you're just using pug as an awesomely simple html template language) then you can use gulp-pug to convert them into static html files.

Comment: @Graham The top answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101502/nodejs-express-nginx-and-jade-whats-the-deal lead me to believe caching would solve my problem. I've successfully implemented gulp-pug, at least locally, but I'm still getting "cannot get /"... So there must be something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, it must be an nginx configuration issue (something I have no experience in yet)

Comment: @Graham Thats okay, well thanks for your help! I appreciate what you could help me with.

Comment: I wish you luck, as I might be in this position next year :)